# When we use 'notEmpty' and 'blank' model validation rules in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

While doing validation..I get a question in mind that is "**When we use notEmpty and blank model validation rules?**". I goggled it but there is no clarification. Please clarify with example.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**'blank'** - MUST be empty or only whitespace characters.

**'notEmpty'** - it CANNOT be empty

---

All of this information is clearly explained in the CakePHP book under "validation":

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html